# WCF Endpoints Exposing Multiple Contracts in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am able to customize the ServiceHost on a WcfCommunicationListener from **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795147/exposing-wcf-tcp-endpoints-from-service-fabric-with-ws-metadataexchange-for-exte)** that I submitted the other day. However, I'm now getting some very strange behavior from Service Fabric when hosting multiple WCF endpoints on a stateless service.

I am assigning multiple listeners to the ServiceInstanceListner array:[image]

I am ensuring that they each have a unique name, as well as unique contracts, and custom endpoints and paths.

When deployed to ServiceFabric they both show up as expected as enpoints on that service:

[image]

And when I fire up my WcfTestClient and call one of the endpoints I get back the methods as expected:

[image]

However once I call the other service the strangeness begins, I can see both contracts being exposed on the same endpoint:

[image]

Calling the initial endpoint a second time yields similar results:

[image]

If I add service references from a Visual Studio project the same issue occurs. I've also pushed this to a cluster on Azure to make sure it wasn't a local issue.

I've combed through my code hundreds of times to ensure that neither listener/servicehost shares any contracts, endpoints or other implementation details with the other so I am at a loss as to how to keep these isolated.

I have very similar code that I am migrating from a Cloud Services project and have never seen this before when working in that platform. Any ideas on how to ensure endpoint isolation? I tried using separate ports to no avail and am at a loss.

I did notice in the config file generated by WcfTestClient that I have both netTcpBindings represented on each service - but I cannot tell if this is a symptom or a cause:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to repro this issue but it worked as expected.
I have uploaded the sample here 
https://github.com/suchiagicha/Samples

You could then tell us if you are doing anything different.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow and let you know if it works and if so will compare with my solution and post my findings.

Comment: Thank you, your sample worked as expected and I was able to implement your recipe for endpoint creation into my solution and it now works as expected. I'm not 100% sure why my code didn't work - but I did notice that your method requires that the metadata exchange endpoints are on a different port from the listener (otherwise it causes an exception on Service Fabric). That may have made all the difference.